# Fix Python3 syntax error in CheckMK plugin

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-3.4

I'm using CheckMK 2.2.0 and its plugin for Nginx to monitor some hosts. The agent is running on a host using Python 3.4.2 that can not be updated. When running the Nginx plugin on this host, I'm getting a syntax error:

```
# python3 nginx_status.py
  File "nginx_status.py", line 126
    config: dict = {}
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code looks like:

```
def main():  # pylint: disable=too-many-branches
    config_dir = os.getenv("MK_CONFDIR", "/etc/check_mk")
    config_file = config_dir + "/nginx_status.cfg"

    config: dict = {}
    if os.path.exists(config_file):
        with open(config_file) as open_config_file:
            config_src = open_config_file.read()
            exec(config_src, globals(), config)
```

Running this script on another host using Python 3.11.2 it works. But as I've said, I'm not able to update the elder Python version. I'm a PHP programmer, but have no knowledge of Python.

What is this type of code `config: dict = {}` and how to fix it to run on Python 3.4?

Comment: But to answer your question, simply remove ': dict' and keep `config = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.4 is too old to support [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). You *really* should get it upgraded to a secure and supported version. [3.4 reached end of life](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) on 2019-03-18.

In the interim, the workaround is to remove any type annotations from the source code. Anything which looks like `variable: type = value` or `variable: type` should lose the `: type` part. Similarly, function definitions with a `-> returntype` annotation should lose that.

For example,

```
def foo(bar: int, baz: str = "") -> bool:
   temp: str = f"{bar}!={baz}"
   return temp == "1!=2"
```

should be refactored to

```
def foo(bar, baz=""):
   temp = f"{bar}!={baz}"
   return temp == "1!=2"
```

for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know type hints from PHP. That fixed it for now and I know that these systems have to be upgraded or replaced ASAP.